# is this correct use of the back button

Tags: android, back

I have the impression that I am fighting a losing battle on how to use the Back button. (Note that part of this battle is fought with non-Android users.)

One argument I often encounter is that many apps would no longer respect, or reduce the concept of back navigation. I also experienced that many users no longer use back navigation, but Up instead.

In this case, I have an activity A, a form that also allows the user to define an *optional* piece of information (a location on a map). to specify the location, an activity B is called up that shows the map, where the user can tap a location.

The user is supposed to indicate a spot, then go back to A and continue whatever (s)he was inputting, to complete the form.

But (some?) users seem to prefer an explicit "done" or "apply" button (note that I haven't foreseen a "cancel" action yet, but I would add that).

Is using Back (to acknowledge the selected location and return to the form) the wrong way to complete this action?

**Edit 1**: let's assume I add an OK (or DONE) and a CANCEL action to map activity B. Should Back act as a cancel, or as a confirm? I would tend to say Confirm (see also [[flowchart](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/confirming-acknowledging.html)), and provide an acknowledging toast. And that's why to me, an OK button is just duplicated effort (further reducing the Back concept). (Admitted, adding an OK button is no big deal.)

Comment: you may simply use the ok button in such a case which will automatically lead you to the previous activity. but what if she don't want to enter the location either she want to look back for a while or she want to just confirm what she need to enter in the map.  in that case back button will help. In my vision back button should always be there. you consider any good app they will provide you back button. it enhances the user experiance

Comment: You can have both approaches as per your suitability. All back button does is navigates to the immediate previous `Activity` visited and removes current from the stack. You can either override the Back button function or add your own button to do the same. The simplest is to `finish()` current activity.

Comment: Default back button behavior is to go back a step in navigation history akin to browser's back. If I were a user, what you want to do sounds like cancelling. So to me it doesn't look like I confirmed anything.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, using back button(to acknowledge the selected location and return to the form) is a wrong way to complete this action. Back button navigation should be used only when the user wants to see previous activity without any data submission from the user in the current activity. If the user wants to submit some data, there should be Submit/Done/Apply Button. That is how the user perception is nowadays. User is trained to do so in all the apps he uses or else there is a doubt in user's mind as to whether he has really submitted the data.

Answer (score 1):

I think that it is the wrong way because, The `back` button is meant to be used to return or Undo something on the flow of actions the user is supposed to do, if user is tapping a location in the map, it could think that pressing back would clean out that selected coordenates (at least I would) instead of being part of a coherent flow. 
I suggest an action bar with `DONE` and a check icon, that's the easy way for the user to know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the average android phone setup. It is not a back button nor is it a done button that confirms  your change. It is committed the moment you make the change. So I guess if you have to make a choice, choose the one that comes closest to the native UI.
I myself do not think there is a right or wrong, only awkward and non-akward UI behaviour.